# Python web scrape - can't display js content

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The old script was working until yesterday. In page source it used to display the web content, e.g. "IssuesTraded 3,037 3,025 3,030", but not any more.. can't figure out what changed..

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe")

urlpage = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks/marketsdiary'
browser.get(urlpage)
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']//*[@class='style--grid--3gzjbqou ']")

# print('Number of results', len(results))
data = []
for result in results:
    data.append(result.text)

data = [x.split("\n") for x in data]
data = [y for x in data for y in x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have linked to a class name that can change dynamically:

```
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']//*[@class='style--grid--3gzjbqou ']")
```

They probably updated the app, so `3gzjbqou` is no longer there. Instead of linking to the full class name, you can make this locator more stable by removing `3gzjbqou` piece and only link to the part of that class.

So try this line instead of yours for searching `results`:

```
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']//*[contains(@class, 'style--grid')]")
```

I hope this helps, good luck!